# Download pdf in javascript and embed it

Tags: javascript, html, http

I have a webservice that will respond with a pdf on certain post requests.

I need to be able, in javascript, to download this pdf and embed it on my page. How would I do that?

I don't have a direct URL only the data passed back by the AJAX

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). However, [it doesn't support all the browser.](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported)

An alternative with IE support is thatyou could just insert a iFrame, and change the src to the location of the PDF.